# pose, impose, expose and compose

Tags: meaning, verbs, vocabulary

Studying vocabularies, I am very confused about the meaning of those words. In the view of a learner, those seem very similar to me, but I cannot find the relation of them. Is there any relationship between those words, or they have independent meanings?

Comment: There's quite a bit about this in [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pose). To a first approximation though, ***pose*** = *to put, place in position*. How much do you already know, and what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: They all came from French according to Etymology Online Dictionary. They have completely different meanings. You need to study and learn them by looking up the dictionary and reading their usages. Please visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: First you need to dispose of the notion that similar looking words have similar meanings.  It is often the case that this is true, but usually there are at least nuances to individual words that are not obvious from the Greek/Latin/French/German/Norse roots.  And there are some notable cases where assuming similar spelling ==> similar meaning can lead you badly astray.  Use similar spellings as a clue, but use a dictionary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSE = TO PUT, from Old French (actually contemporary french "poser" is still valid).

when posing you are in a position that you have put yourself into.
when exposing you are placing something for public view.
when imposing you are forcibly placing something/some idea.
when composing you are placing various words/sounds together.

According to THE [Merriam Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/):

"Origin of POSE
Middle English, from Anglo-French poser, from Vulgar Latin *pausare, from Late Latin, to stop, rest, pause, from Latin pausa pause
First Known Use: 14th century

Origin of EXPOSE
Middle English, from Anglo-French exposer, from Latin exponere to set forth, explain (perfect indicative exposui), from ex- + ponere to put, place — more at position
First Known Use: 15th century

Origin of IMPOSE
Middle French imposer, from Latin imponere, literally, to put upon (perfect indicative imposui), from in- + ponere to put — more at position
First Known Use: 1581

Origin of COMPOSE
Middle English, from Anglo-French composer, from Latin componere (perfect indicative composui) — more at compound
First Known Use: 15th century"

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvoter, a plague on this site.

Comment: Please improve this answer by explicitly noting the prefixes *ex-* (out), *im-* (in, on), and *com-* (with).  Point out other words in this lineage -- *de*pose, *re*pose, *sup*pose, as well any that don't, like *adipose*.  Be sure to note that the etymology gives an understanding of the development of the word, but isn't dispositive (See what I did there?) of meaning.  For instance, when a lawyer *de*poses you, you have to understand what is put down are your words, in writing.